# The command "./gradlew build connectedCheck" exited with 1

Tags: android, github, gradle, travis-ci

used: github,  gradle, travis CI to build my Android project.
something issues:
......
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:validateMyConfigSigning
:packageRelease
:zipalignRelease FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':zipalignRelease'.

> File '/usr/local/android-sdk/tools/zipalign' specified for property 'zipAlignExe' does not exist.
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   BUILD FAILED
>   Total time: 1 mins 26.33 secs
>   The command "./gradlew build connectedCheck" exited with 1.
>   Done. Your build exited with 1.
>   ......

the following is my :build.gradle file:
please help me.thanks

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
    //乱码
 tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { options.encoding = "UTF-8" }  
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: "$buildDir/native-libs", include: 'native-libs.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"
 //key
 signingConfigs {
  myConfig{
   storeFile file("debug.keystore")
   storePassword "android"
   keyAlias "androiddebugkey"
   keyPassword "android"
  }
 }
 buildTypes{
  release {
   signingConfig signingConfigs.myConfig
   //代码混淆
   //runProguard true  
            //proguardFile 'proguard.cfg'
  } 
 }
 //应用版本
 defaultConfig {
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.01"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
 //文件
    sourceSets {
        main {
         manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
         java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
        
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
     androidTest {
       java.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
       res.srcDirs = ['tests/res']
       assets.srcDirs = ['tests/assets']
       resources.srcDirs = ['tests/src']
     }
    }
 
    //for .so files
    task nativeLibsToJar(type: Zip, description: 'create a jar archive of the native libs') {
     destinationDir file("$buildDir/native-libs")
     baseName 'native-libs'
     extension 'jar'
     from fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '**/*.so')
     into 'lib/'
 }
 
 tasks.withType(Compile) {
     compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn(nativeLibsToJar)
 } 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

indicate that it is *not* an inner class.
:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:validateMyConfigSigning
:packageRelease
:zipalignRelease FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':zipalignRelease'.

> File '/usr/local/android-sdk/tools/zipalign' specified for property 'zipAlignExe' does not exist.
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   BUILD FAILED
>   Total time: 1 mins 26.33 secs
>   The command "./gradlew build connectedCheck" exited with 1.
>   Done. Your build exited with 1.